# Is it a problem if my father's name is different in my new passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My old Egyptian passport with a valid USA visa has my father's name as Fekry. My new valid passport has it spelled Fikry. Will this be a problem when entering the US?

Comment: Nobody cares about that.

Comment: Most countries don't list **any** family members in a passport, except the underage children of the passport holder, if at all. This information is totally irrelevant for them - I can't even think of why Egypt would.

Answer (score 6):

No it will not.

Your name should be spelled correctly; and your old visa is still valid even though your passport has expired. Make sure you carry both passports with you when you travel.